# Celery - Granular tasks vs. message passing overhead

Tags: celery, parallel-processing

The Celery docs section [Performance and Strategies](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#granularity) suggests that tasks with multiple 'steps' should be divided into subtasks for more efficient parallelization. It then mentions that (of course) there will be more message passing overhead, so dividing into subtasks may not be worth the overhead.

In my case, I have an overall task of retrieving a small image (150px x 115px) from a third party API, then uploading via HTTP to my site's REST API. I can either implement this as a single task, or divide up the steps of retrieving the image and then uploading it into two seperate tasks. If I go with seperate tasks, I assume I will have to pass the image as part of the message to the second task.

My question is, which approach should be better in this case, and how can I measure the performance in order to know for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your jobs are I/O-constrained, dividing the task may increase the number of operations that can be done in parallel. The message-passing overhead is likely to be tiny since any capable broker should be able to handle lots of messages/second with only a few ms of latency.

In your case, uploading the image will probably take longer than downloading it. With separate tasks, the download jobs needn't wait for uploads to finish (so long as there are available workers). Another advantage of separation is that you can put each job on different queue and dedicate more workers as backed-up queues reveal themselves.

If I were to try to benchmark this, I would compare execution times using same number of workers for each of the two strategies.  For instance 2 workers on the combined task vs 2 workers on the divided one.  Then do 4 workers on each and so on.  My inclination is that the separated task will show itself to be faster; especially when the worker count is increased.